# Start css3 animation on every slide from the slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using flex slider in my project.

I did 3 css3 animations, when the website loads the animations are running perfect on the first slide, but when changing to the 2 slide the aniamtions are not starting.

I need help to start the css animations when the slideshow is scrolling slides.

my code js - initialize the slider:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('._il_slider_box_wrapper_').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        start: function(){
            $('._il_slider_box_wrapper_').resize();
        }
    });
});
```

my html:

```
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="../main_slide_tab_1.jpg" style="margin-bottom: -4px;" class="_il_slider_box_wrapper_img_" />

            <span class="_il_slider_box_slide_wrapper_"></span>

            <span class="_il_slider_box_slide_box_">

                <span class="_il_slider_box_slide_box_block_">
                    <span class="_il_slider_box_slide_box_sub_">
                        <span class="_il_slider_box_slide_box_icon_block">
                            <span class="_il_slider_box_slide_box_icon_">
                                <img src="../_il_lock_icon_slide_.png" style="width: 75px;margin-top: 30px;" />
                            </span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="_il_slider_box_slide_box_title_">Segregated Bank Accounts</span>
                    </span>

                </span>

            </span>

        </li>

    </ul>
```

The animation that I want to start on everyslide are these elements:

```
._il_slider_box_slide_box_icon_
._il_slider_box_slide_box_title_
```

css for the class ._il_slider_box_slide_box_icon_

```
._il_slider_box_slide_box_icon_{  
  -webkit-animation: _il_animation_roll_ 1s ease-out both, _il_animation_fadeIn_ 1s ease-out both;
  -moz-animation: _il_animation_roll_ 1s ease-out both, _il_animation_fadeIn_ 1s ease-out both;
  -o-animation: _il_animation_roll_ 1s ease-out both, _il_animation_fadeIn_ 1s ease-out both;
  -ms-animation: _il_animation_roll_ 1s ease-out both, _il_animation_fadeIn_ 1s ease-out both;
  animation: _il_animation_roll_ 1s ease-out both, _il_animation_fadeIn_ 1s ease-out both;
}
```

css for the class ._il_slider_box_slide_box_title_

```
._il_slider_box_slide_box_title_{
  -webkit-animation: _il_animation_moveUp_ 1s ease-in-out both;
  -moz-animation: _il_animation_moveUp_ 1s ease-in-out both;
  -o-animation: _il_animation_moveUp_ 1s ease-in-out both;
  -ms-animation: _il_animation_moveUp_ 1s ease-in-out both;
  animation: _il_animation_moveUp_ 1s ease-in-out both;
}
```

key-frames

```
@-webkit-keyframes _il_animation_roll_{
  0% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-500px) rotate(-360deg);}
  100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes _il_animation_roll_{
  0% {-moz-transform: translateX(-500px) rotate(-360deg); opacity: 0;}
  100% {-moz-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg); opacity: 1;}
}
@-o-keyframes _il_animation_roll_{
  0% {-o-transform: translateX(-500px) rotate(-360deg); opacity: 0;}
  100% {-o-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg); opacity: 1;}
}
@-ms-keyframes _il_animation_roll_{
  0% {-ms-transform: translateX(-500px) rotate(-360deg); opacity: 0;}
  100% {-ms-transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg); opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes _il_animation_roll_{
  0% {transform: translateX(-500px) rotate(-360deg); opacity: 0;}
  100% {transform: translateX(0px) rotate(0deg); opacity: 1;}
}


@-webkit-keyframes _il_animation_fadeIn_{
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@-moz-keyframes _il_animation_fadeIn_{
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@-o-keyframes _il_animation_fadeIn_{
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@-ms-keyframes _il_animation_fadeIn_{
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes _il_animation_fadeIn_{
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}


@-webkit-keyframes _il_animation_moveUp_{
  0% {-webkit-transform: translateY(40px);}
  100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);}
}
@-moz-keyframes _il_animation_moveUp_{
  0% {-moz-transform: translateY(40px);}
  100% {-moz-transform: translateY(0px);}
}
@-o-keyframes _il_animation_moveUp_{
  0% {-o-transform: translateY(40px);}
  100% {-o-transform: translateY(0px);}
}
@-ms-keyframes _il_animation_moveUp_{
  0% {-ms-transform: translateY(40px);}
  100% {-ms-transform: translateY(0px);}
}
@keyframes _il_animation_moveUp_{
  0% {transform: translateY(40px);}
  100% {transform: translateY(0px);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Post your code CSS code so we can see, animations are CSS not JS.

//NOTE: You can build this entire slider without JS using CSS3 @keyframe animations.

Comment: i am using flexsslider like a standard slider, but i need special aniamtions for extra elements, so i did them in css3 but can not manage to start aniamtion on every slide separated

Comment: You need use a timing mechanism in js for the slide show and then group the "extra-elements" between each individual slide. So in between your intervals slide1(1-10) slide2(10-20) slide3(20-30) and so on.

Comment: i did the same as u did, but when i add the second <li> to add a second slide the css3 aniamtions are not running, seems they run all together on the first slide, but i want that the aniamtion will run on each slide @JordanDavis